# some hidden character in json encode

Tags: php, json, string, hidden, non-ascii-characters

i use jdate library in order to convert gregorian date to jalali and after explode the day and the month i found some hidden characters added to my string and when i encode them to json i cannot parse it

```
{
    "result": [{
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 6"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 7"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 8"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 9"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 10"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 11"
    }, {
        "year": " 1394",
        "month": " 12"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 1"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 2"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 3"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 4"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 5"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 6"
    }, {
        "year": " 1395",
        "month": " 7"
    }]
}
```

i cannot remove the hidden characters , they are placed at the first of the json string , please help me to solve it !

here is my code :

```
$termID = (isset($_REQUEST['term_id'])) ? $this->db()->safe($_REQUEST['term_id']) : '';

    $sel="SELECT term_id, term_from_date, term_to_date  FROM  {$this->var->db_perfix}edu_term where term_id=$termID GROUP BY term_id";
    $arrFromTo = $this->db()->q($sel);

    $arrFromTo[0]->{'term_from_date'} = $this->jdate( "Y-m-j" , strtotime($arrFromTo[0]->{'term_from_date'}) );
    $arrFromTo[0]->{'term_to_date'} = $this->jdate( "Y-m-j" , strtotime($arrFromTo[0]->{'term_to_date'}) );

    $fromDate = explode('-', $arrFromTo[0]->{'term_from_date'});

    $fromYear = $fromDate[0];
    $fromMonth = $fromDate[1];

    $toDate = explode('-', $arrFromTo[0]->{'term_to_date'});

    $toYear = $toDate[0];
    $toMonth = $toDate[1];

    $count = $toMonth - $fromMonth + 1 +  ($toYear - $fromYear)*12 ;

    $arrMonth = array();
    $arrMonthNum = array();
    $yearNum = $fromYear;

    $j = 0;

    for($i=0 ; $i<=$count ; $i++){
        $monthNum = ($fromMonth+$i)%12;
        $yearNum += ($monthNum==1)? 1 : 0;
        $monthNum = ($monthNum)? $monthNum : 12;

        $arrMonth['result'][$j]['year'] .= ($count>=12) ? ' '.$yearNum : '' ;
        $arrMonth['result'][$j]['month'] .= ($count>=12) ? ' '.$monthNum : '' ;


        //$arrMonth['result'][$monthNum."-".$yearNum]['year'] .= ($count>=12) ? ' '.$yearNum : '' ;
        // $arrMonth['result'][$monthNum."-".$yearNum]['month'] .= ($count>=12) ? ' '.$monthNum : '' ;

        $gregorian = $this->jalali_to_gregorian($yearNum , $monthNum , 1);
        $monthDuring = $this->lastday($gregorian[1]+1 , 1 , $gregorian[0]);

        $firsDayOfMonth = date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, $gregorian[1], $gregorian[2] , $gregorian[0]));
        $lastDayOfMonth =  date("N", mktime(0, 0, 0, $gregorian[1], $gregorian[2]+$monthDuring-1 , $gregorian[0]));

        if($firsDayOfMonth==6 or $firsDayOfMonth==7)
            $firsDayOfMonth = $firsDayOfMonth-6;
        else
            $firsDayOfMonth++;

        if($lastDayOfMonth==6 or $lastDayOfMonth==7)
            $lastDayOfMonth = $lastDayOfMonth-6;
        else
            $lastDayOfMonth++;

        $j++;
    }

    $a = trim(json_encode($arrMonth,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),"\x00..\x1F");

    echo $a;
```

Comment: This JSON seems to be correct

Comment: Can you show us the code where you parse it to JSON. Then we maybe can find the reason why there are extra characters added.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using ? It would maybe help understand what's going on.

Comment: PHP's `json_encode()` function never generates invalid JSON so those characters should come from outside. Perhaps your editor is configured to add a BOM on top of UTF-8 source code files :-?

Comment: i add my code to question , i cannot understand why those characters added ? , i check all the things but it doesn't work

Comment: Go look up what the keyword that @Álvaro mentioned means: BOM

Comment: Sorry but I find statements on the line of "tried all, didn't work" too vague to have a meaning (just like "couldn't find information in Google"). What did you try exactly and how did it fail to work? You didn't ask for clarifications about BOM because it's clear enough and you're just finding the time to verify it?